# SQL - How to link two tables with a third table and get all records

Tags: sql-server-2008

Okay, so these are my three tables:

**USER**

```
|--------+----------+----------|
| UserID | UserName | IsActive |
|--------+----------+----------|
|   10   |   Mike   |     1    |
|   11   |   John   |     1    |
|   12   |   Beth   |     1    |
|--------+----------+----------|
```

**REPORT_DISTRIB** (Linking Table)

```
|-----------+--------+----------+---------------|
| DistribID | UserID | ReportID | DistribToUser |
|-----------+--------+----------+---------------|
|     1     |   10   |    50    |       1       |
|     2     |   12   |    52    |       0       |
|     3     |   14   |    54    |       1       |
|-----------+--------+----------+---------------|
```

**REPORT**

```
|----------+------------+---------------|
| ReportID | ReportName | Distributable |
|----------+------------+---------------|
|    50    |   FY2010   |       1       |
|    51    |   FY2011   |       1       |
|    52    |   FY2012   |       1       |
|----------+------------+---------------|
```

In the problem I'm facing, I have 200 users from the USER table that are active and 10 reports from the REPORT table that are distributable. For every user I need to display the User Name, the Report Name, and whether that report should be distributed to the user, like so:

```
|----------+------------+---------------|
| UserName | ReportName | DistribToUser |
|----------+------------+---------------|
|   Mike   |   FY2010   |       1       |
|   Beth   |   FY2012   |       0       |
|----------+------------+---------------|
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a list of 2000 results (200 users x 10 reports). The problem is that the REPORT_DISTRIB linking table doesn't have a record for every user with each report. I still feel like this should be possible... am I wrong in my thinking? Any help is greatly appreciated.

It's rough, but this is my query so far (which returns 1790 results):

```
SELECT u.UserName, r.ReportName, rd.DistribToUser
FROM USER u
LEFT JOIN REPORT_DISTRIB rd on rd.UserID = u.UserID
  and rd.ReportID in (select r.ReportID from REPORT r where r.Distributable = 1)
OUTER APPLY (select r.ReportName from REPORT r where r.ReportID = rd.ReportID) r
WHERE u.IsActive = 1
```

Comment: So to be I correctly understand you want to return 10 rows for each 200 users, 1 row for each report for each user.  In the case where that user has a linking record with that report put a 1 in the other case put a 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT u.UserName, r.ReportName, COALESCE(rd.DistribToUser, 0)
    FROM USER u
        CROSS JOIN REPORT r
        LEFT JOIN REPORT_DISTRIB rd
            ON u.UserID = rd.UserID
                AND r.ReportID = rd.ReportID
    WHERE u.IsActive = 1
        AND r.Distributable = 1
```

Comment: Here's a link to information about Cross Joins.. http://www.sqlguides.com/sql_cross_join.php  Cross Joins will return every possible combination. Then, you left join the results of that with what other data you need (in this case, DistribToUser)

Comment: Wow! thanks Joe! I thought I might need to do a cross join, but I didn't know how to use it. I added one more condition to the WHERE clause (and r.Distributable = 1) and it works like a charm!